# Make string from JS array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have array:

`const arr = ["This is Sparta", "Yes it is", "Hello"];`

And i want string output like this:

`const str = "This is Sparta,
    Yes it is,
    Hello"`

So, after each comma in array i need break line in string.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 6):

`.join()` will join your array values in one string and add after each value the character that you passed to it as argument, so `,\n` will add comma after each word and `\n` will add line break

```js
const arr = ["This is Sparta", "Yes it is", "Hello"];

console.log(arr.join(",\n"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.join()` method by passing `,\n` as argument:

```js
const arr = ["This is Sparta", "Yes it is", "Hello"];

const str = arr.join(",\n");

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Join array with `,\n` as you want comma and a line break

```js
const arr = ["This is Sparta", "Yes it is", "Hello"];

let op = arr.join(',\n')
console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 0):

.join() function works for you. You can coustomise according to your needs in parameter.

`arr=["This is Sparta", "Yes it is", "Hello"];
str= arr.join(',\n')`

And in general way. If someone want to manually add comma and space.
`str= arr[0]+','+'\n'+arr[1]+','+'\n'+arr[2];`